# Elastic Beanstalk fails to launch in custom VPC and subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform

My Elastic Beanstalk env fails to launch due to connectivity between the EC2 and Elastic Beanstalk:

```sh
 Error: Error waiting for Elastic Beanstalk Environment (e-xxxxxxxxxx) to become ready: 2 errors occurred:

    * 2021-02-16 11:00:21.529 +0000 UTC (e-xxxxxxxxxx) : 
            Stack named 'awseb-e-xxxxxxxxxx-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED'  
            Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [AWSEBInstanceLaunchWaitCondition].

    * 2021-02-16 11:00:21.662 +0000 UTC (e-xxxxxxxxxx) : 
            The EC2 instances failed to communicate with AWS Elastic Beanstalk, either because of configuration problems with the VPC or a failed EC2 instance. Check your VPC configuration and try launching the environment again.
```

However, I can SSH into the EC2 instance, where I find the following:

```sh
$ tail /var/log/eb-cfn-init.log 
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:02:09 --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to elasticbeanstalk-platform-assets-eu-west-2.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com port 443: Connection timed out
+ RESULT=7
+ [[ 7 -ne 0 ]]
+ sleep_delay
+ ((  40 < 3600  ))
+ echo Sleeping 40
Sleeping 40
+ sleep 40
```

This error surprises me, because I have an S3 VPC endpoint in this VPC:

```
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "s3_endpoint_public" {
  vpc_id       = aws_vpc.main.id
  service_name = "com.amazonaws.${var.aws_region}.s3"
}

resource "aws_vpc_endpoint_route_table_association" "s3_public_route_table_association" {
  route_table_id  = aws_route_table.public.id
  vpc_endpoint_id = aws_vpc_endpoint.s3_endpoint_public.id
}
```

How can I debug / fix my Elastic Beanstalk environment?

---

Route table / subnet configuration

```
resource "aws_route_table" "public" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "public_a" {
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.public.id
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.public_c.id
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "public_b" {
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.public.id
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.public_c.id
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "public_c" {
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.public.id
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.public_c.id
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "public" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id
}

resource "aws_route" "public_internet" {
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.public.id
  gateway_id     = aws_internet_gateway.public.id

  destination_cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
}
```

Comment: s3 endpoint only is not enough. If you don't want to use nat, you also need endpoints to CloudFormation, EB itself and more. Have you check [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/vpc.html#services-vpc-private) on using EB with VPC?

Comment: I have endpoints for CloudFormation, SQS, Kinesis, Elastic Beanstalk and Elastic Beanstalk Health. I only mention the S3 one because the logs show the EC2 failed to connect to S3.

Comment: I see. Can you please clarify what is `aws_route_table.public`? Is it route table in a public subnet, or private? Is it same subnet as your EB?

Comment: I just noticed that `aws_subnet.public_c` is associated 3 times! The error is just a typo...

Comment: So you have S3 vpn endpoint in a public subnet? So you EB instances are also in public subnet?

Comment: @Marcin yes the EB instances need internet access

Comment: I see. But if instances are in public subnets, do you really need all these VPC endpoints?

Comment: @Marcin yes I am removing those. I added them as an experiment because it wasn't working

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the subnets are associated with a route table, and that the route table has an internet gateway.

Answer (score 0):

At that moment, we verified that amazon unchecks the public ip option and the machine cannot access https://elasticbeanstalk-platform-assets-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/stalks/eb_docker_amazon_linux_2_1.0.2471.0_20230327194222/ lib/UserDataScript.sh , thus causing a problem in docker.
What you need to do is put the machine with internet access.